# Logback: Load groovy config

Tags: java, logback, logback-groovy

How can I programmatically load custom named groovy config (`logback-config.groovy`) config?
When I tries:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.reset();
JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
configurator.doConfigure(this.getClass().getResource("/logback-config.groovy"));
```

Got expt:

> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Problem parsing XML
>   document. See previously reported errors.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the `JoranConfigurator` is specific only for XML configurations; for Groovy config files, logback uses a different class `GafferConfigurator`. (Unfortunately, the logback documentation does not do a good job of advertising this fact.) But rather than reference the `GafferConfigurator` directly, it would be better to use the `ContextInitializer` class instead:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.reset();
new ContextInitializer(loggerContext).configureByResource(this.getClass().getResource("/logback-config.groovy"));
```

This allows you to handle both XML and Groovy filetypes simultaneously, as well as take advantage of some of logback's built-in error checking.